# MacOS Mojave: Require sudo to execute a file

Tags: macos, sudo

I have a bash script. I want to transfer ownership of that file to root such that a sudo password is required to execute the script. How would I accomplish this on Mac? Thanks!

Comment: The same as in any other UNIX!

Answer (score 0):

I asked to early! The following worked:

`sudo chown root:admin script.sh`

`sudo chmod 700 script.sh`